# Is there a name for this pattern of composing a type safe return type from different levels of nested related entities?

Tags: design-patterns, generics, data-types

I have a problem in my app where I have many entities that can all reference each other in different ways. For example, I have a `Job` (e.g. build house) that I might assign to a team called "Plumbers" and a separate single user called "Bob". `Job`s, `Team`s and `User`s are all entities with unique ids.

When I make a request for this data I want to be able to compose the depth of data I want and if my returned type should contain ids or objects. The goal is to still keep the type safety for the return type.

For example I may just want the `JobSummary`, which will give me the name of the job, and the ids of the `User`s and the `Team`s assigned.

Alternatively I may want to request the full "tree" of data where IDs are resolved to actual entities. I'll call this the `HydratedJob`. I'm not sure if "hydrated" is the right term, but I've heard it used in this sense a lot. In this case the `HydratedJob` will contain a User object, and a Team object. That team object, in turn will contain a list of User objects.

I would really like to know if this is a pattern with a name that I could research more, and if anyone knows any pitfalls of this approach as I'm looking to integrate it in my app.

Below I've made an implementation of this in Kotlin to demonstrate:

All entities or entity IDs implement this:

```
interface Identifiable {
    val value: String
}
```

For the Job entity I create an interface that is either implemented by just the id, or the full entity (`FlexibleJob`). I call it flexible, because the job can either contain ids or objects for other entities. A type parameter specifies which of these must be provided.

```
interface IdentifiableJob : Identifiable
data class JobId(override val value: String) : IdentifiableJob
data class FlexibleJob<USER : IdentifiableUser, TEAM : IdentifiableTeam>(
        val jobId: JobId,
        val name: String,
        val users: List<USER>,
        val teams: List<TEAM>
) : IdentifiableJob {
    override val value = jobId.value
}
```

I do the same for teams and users.

```
interface IdentifiableTeam : Identifiable
data class TeamId(override val value: String) : IdentifiableTeam
data class FlexibleTeam<USER : IdentifiableUser>(
        val teamId: TeamId,
        val name: String,
        val users: List<USER>? = null
) : IdentifiableTeam {
    override val value = teamId.value
}

interface IdentifiableUser : Identifiable
data class UserId(override val value: String) : IdentifiableUser
data class User(val userId: UserId,
                val name: String) : IdentifiableUser {
    override val value = userId.value
}
```

Then I use `typealias`es to make the list of type parameters easier to read (there could be about 10 type parameters, with multiple nesting of type parameters :O). Here I achieve my goal of being able to compose data types with any level of nesting I want.

```
typealias SummaryJob = FlexibleJob<IdentifiableUser, IdentifiableTeam> // No nested objects, just ids
typealias SummaryTeam = FlexibleTeam<IdentifiableUser>
typealias HydratedTeam = FlexibleTeam<User>
typealias PartiallyHydratedJob = FlexibleJob<User, SummaryTeam>
typealias HydratedJob = FlexibleJob<User, HydratedTeam> // All objects nested, no ids
```

Then below you can see that type safety works

```
fun main() {
    val userId = UserId("user-id")
    val user = User(userId = userId, name = "Bob")
    val summaryTeam = SummaryTeam(
            teamId = TeamId("team-id"),
            name = "Plumbers",
            users = listOf(userId)
    )
    val hydratedTeam = HydratedTeam(
            teamId = TeamId("team-id"),
            name = "Plumbers",
            users = listOf(user)
    )

    // Fails with type mis-match compile error. Expecting User not UserId and expecting HydratedTeam not SummaryTeam. This is good type safety.
    val attemptFullyHydratedJobForDisplay = HydratedJob(JobId("123"),
                                                              "Build stuff",
                                                              listOf(userId),
                                                              listOf(summaryTeam))

    // Compiles
    val fullyHydratedJobForDisplay = HydratedJob(JobId("123"), "Build stuff", listOf(user), listOf(hydratedTeam))
}
```

Comment: Sounds a bit like (lazy) loading related data. In ORM's like Entity Framework you can specify an object and the Id for that object in the same entity. When you query the entity, only the Id is loaded, but you can specify to include the full object in the query (eager loading) or configure the ORM to automatically query the related data when properties of the object are accessed (lazy loading). Is this what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: Kind of. I'm not so concerned about lazy loading for performance though. I want to be able to specify return types that are composed of multiple entities in a shape that the caller chooses.

Comment: But yes it is similar to where you say you can specify to include the full object in the query (also kind of like graphql?). The important part is that the return type is type safe for that particular query.

Comment: It is still performance though. If not for performance concerns, in theory you could have implemented so that it always populate the full tree of objects.

Comment: Good point, but in the real problem (not this simple example) there is no known "full tree". The tree could literally go forever.

Comment: This question needs a Kotlin tag, or a language-specific tag, and/or a dependent-types tag (covers generics, templates, and more). It makes use of Kotlin generics and wants to see what limits it can be pushed to and what benefits it would bring to OP's use case.

Comment: Meanwhile JSON-based protocols handle this with ease, but it would have none of the "type safety" (or actually compiler reasoning of return types) that OP wants. It is indeed strongly related to "deferred loading" as this approach avoids the rough corner of " you get exactly what you asked for and you aren't allowed to ask more" approach.

Comment: I guess I could always load the fullest tree that I currently ever need, but then then if one particular user object isn't available on one obscure team, wouldn't I have to fail loading all jobs? I tried adding the kotlin tag but it doesn't exist! I would say this is reasonably language agnostic though. Typealiases are basically required though

Comment: Kotlin isn't popular enough for its own tag yet :(. I do wonder when I create a type with possibly 100 type parameters, if the IDE will be able to handle it. I think I felt it slowing down already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you simply have 'lite' and 'full' objects, which is a pretty common anti-pattern.

Whether your object has a child object or just an Id reference is generally governed by deeper concerns than just convenience of display.

After all you can retrieve the child object separately and use it just as easily, if not more easily in most cases.

Does your Job object have methods which call child object methods?

Are child objects shared over multiple parents?

Can you update the underlying data source atomically with the child objects attached?

Can you read the underlying data efficiently to populate your chosen structure?

You may have fallen into the trap of OOP data objects, ie Cat, Dog are Animal, Animals have Legs because they are similar; rather than 'programmatic' OOP ie Array implements IEnumerable and has Items because it needs to in order to function

The alternative is to split your objects logically, for pure data this would probably be mostly 'lite' objects, and assemble as required for the function you are working on.

ie

```
PrintInvoice(jobId) //need child data
{
    Job job = repo.GetJob(jobId)
    Teams teams = repo.getTeamsForJob(job.Id);

    print job.Title
    foreach(id in job.TeamIds)
    {
        print teams[id].TeamName
        print teams[id].Price
    }
}

ListJobs() ///just need top level data
{
    var jobs = repo.GetJobs()
    foreach(j in jobs)
    {
       print j.Title
    }
}
```

Now I can assemble the information from both 'lite' and 'full' objects as I require for a specific task, I've saved huge amounts of code, If i have one team that's in two jobs, then I don't have two copies of it, if I want to list all the teams over multiple jobs I don't have to drill down to child objects and dedupe to get them etc etc

Comment: What is the alternative to lite and full objects? We have quite a few scenarios where we need to specify a certain depth of nesting. Eg when the user clicks "download job" there is a specification for what depth of nesting is required (it's like 5 deep, with 15 different entities). When a user creates a job, it has a different depth. When dealing with these objects I would like to maintain type safety. Retrieving the objects separately really isn't an option for me as the real Job contains about 15 different related entities. These are purely data objects with no methods. .

Comment: Yes child objects have multiple parents. Yes I can update and retrieve the underlying data source atomically. Yes I can read it efficiently enough that performance is not a current concern. There is very little inheritance hierarchy though?

Comment: This is exactly what our data layer looks like. However once I have assembled the information as you say, I would then like that "assembled" data to have it's own specific type. That is because that information needs to be passed along to other classes due to our architecture. Eg we have a Presenter class which will assemble it, but then that will be passed to the view, the list adapter, and the "ViewHolder" (android) and possibly a new page etc. We could make a new plain model for this, a very reasonable alternative, but I'm worried about an explosion of mostly duplicated models.

Comment: For your example of displaying a list of all teams, I would in that case directly make a call to the database using an sql query, with a return type of List<Team>. I would only use my proposed strategy where it is useful.

Comment: you should expect to have a viewmodel per view, but its ineffecient to try and guess a generic view model.

Comment: I agree. I will try that first and leave this approach as a last resort. It is an interesting concept though